# Showing / Hiding components on click based on current state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Disclaimer: I am new to ReactJS

I am trying to implement a dialog window to select a country/language at on the first page of my application.

The idea is the following:

- There is a small flag button on the top right corner that the user can click (CountryFlag)
- When clicked, a dialog (Dialog) shows with 5 countries (flags), and for each country, 2 possible language selection. Choosing a country (for instance **LA**) and language (for instance **lo**) results in a specific locale, for instance **lo-LA**.

My dialog box initially looks like this:

[image: country and language selection]

After clicking on the Vietnamese flag it *should* changes into this:

[image]

After clicking on the country flag, I want two buttons (divs) to appear on the right of the flag so that the user can choose a language. So I am trying to conditionally add the divs based on the current state corresponding to the selected language:

```
<div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={this.selectCountry("KH")} data-country={"KH"} />
{ this.state.countrySelected==="KH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.selectLocale} data-locale={"km-KH"} >ភាសាខ្មែរ</div> : null }
{ this.state.countrySelected==="KH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.selectLocale} data-locale={"en-KH"} >English</div> : null }
```

However, it does not work, there is an error when the dialog box opens, as if the onClick event was triggered already and creating a conflict:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

Here is the complete component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './CountryFlag.css';

var Dialog = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { countrySelected: "" };
    },

    close(){
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.props.container);
    },

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeChild(this.props.container); 
    },

    selectCountry(country) {
        console.log('this is c:', country);
        this.setState({countrySelected: country});
    },

    selectLocale() {
        console.log('this is:', this);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.props.container);
    },

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="Country-dialog-overlay">
                <div className="Country-dialog-inner">
                    <h2>Country > Language</h2>
                    <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={this.selectCountry("KH")} data-country={"KH"} />
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="KH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.selectLocale} data-locale={"km-KH"} >ភាសាខ្មែរ</div> : null }
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="KH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.selectLocale} data-locale={"en-KH"} >English</div> : null }

                    <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={this.selectCountry("LA")} data-country={"LA"} />
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="LA" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"lo-LA"} >ພາສາລາວ</div> : null }
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="LA" ?<div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-LA"} >English</div> : null }

                    <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={this.selectCountry("MM")} data-country={"MM"} />
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="MM" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"my-MM"} >မြန်မာ</div> : null }
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="MM" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-MM"} >English</div> : null }

                    <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={this.selectCountry("TH")} data-country={"TH"} />
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="TH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"th-TH"} >ภาษาไทย</div> : null }
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="TH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-TH"} >English</div> : null }

                    <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={this.selectCountry("VN")} data-country={"VN"} />
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="VN" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"vi-VN"} >Tiếng việt</div> : null }
                    { this.state.countrySelected==="VN" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-VN"} >English</div> : null }
                </div>
            </div>
        );  
    }
});

var Trigger = () => {
    function showDialog() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Dialog container={div}/>,
            document.body.appendChild(div)
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="Country-flag" onClick={showDialog} data-country={"VN"} />
    );
};

class CountryFlag  extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Trigger />
        );
    }
}

export default CountryFlag;
```

Any idea why I have this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
onClick={this.selectCountry("KH")}
```

You're actually calling the function, and not storing a reference to the click handler so that it only fires when clicked. You can either do

```
onClick={() => this.selectCountry("KH")}
```

or even better, make a bound function that passes in the country name, like so

```
onClick={this.selectCountry.bind(this, "KH")}
```

However, since you have `data-` attributes in those elements that you're clicking on, you can put just `onClick={this.selectCountry}` and in the `selectCountry` handler, you can rewrite it like so

```
selectCountry(e) {
  let country = e.currentTarget.dataset.country;
  // country will be "KH" for example
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, +1 for the tip to make use of the data-attribute in an elegant way! the code works now :)

Answer (score 0):

`<div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={this.selectCountry("KH")} data-country={"KH"} />` statement causes the error.

It should be

```
 <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={() => this.selectCountry("KH")} data-country={"KH"} />
```

at every place

The reason it did not work in your case is that onClick expects a function but with `onClick={this.selectCountry("KH")}` you are actually giving it a value retuned by `selectCountry` function. Since you are setting a state in `selectCountry` you render is called again and everytime `render` is called, `selectCountry` is evaluated to return the value to onClick. You need to bind the function in order the pass the value.

You render function will be

```
render(){
    return(
        <div className="Country-dialog-overlay">
            <div className="Country-dialog-inner">
                <h2>Country > Language</h2>
                <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={() => this.selectCountry("KH")} data-country={"KH"} />
                { this.state.countrySelected==="KH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.selectLocale} data-locale={"km-KH"} >ភាសាខ្មែរ</div> : null }
                { this.state.countrySelected==="KH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.selectLocale} data-locale={"en-KH"} >English</div> : null }

                <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={() => this.selectCountry("LA")} data-country={"LA"} />
                { this.state.countrySelected==="LA" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"lo-LA"} >ພາສາລາວ</div> : null }
                { this.state.countrySelected==="LA" ?<div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-LA"} >English</div> : null }

                <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={() => this.selectCountry("MM")} data-country={"MM"} />
                { this.state.countrySelected==="MM" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"my-MM"} >မြန်မာ</div> : null }
                { this.state.countrySelected==="MM" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-MM"} >English</div> : null }

                <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={() => this.selectCountry("TH")} data-country={"TH"} />
                { this.state.countrySelected==="TH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"th-TH"} >ภาษาไทย</div> : null }
                { this.state.countrySelected==="TH" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-TH"} >English</div> : null }

                <div className="Country-flag-big" onClick={() => this.selectCountry("VN")} data-country={"VN"} />
                { this.state.countrySelected==="VN" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"vi-VN"} >Tiếng việt</div> : null }
                { this.state.countrySelected==="VN" ? <div className="Language-big" onClick={this.close} data-locale={"en-VN"} >English</div> : null }
            </div>
        </div>
    );  
}
```